# Requests HTML doesnt get full HTML

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code

```
            response=requests.get(item_url,headers=headers).text
            soup=BeautifulSoup(response,'lxml')
            print(soup)
            
            product=soup.find_all('a',class_='shelfProductTile-descriptionLink')
            print(product)
            price_per_weight=soup.find_all('div',class_='shelfProductTile-cupPrice ng-star-inserted')
            print(price_per_weight)
```

from the url: https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/search/products?searchTerm=uncle%20tobys%20oats%20500g&sortBy=TraderRelevance

I have tried the lxml and html.parser and don't get the classes for the variables above in the requests HTML. I have also tried using cloudscraper as per [Beautiful Soup find_all return None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71885777/beautiful-soup-find-all-return-none)
but still, get an empty list for both product and price_per_weight.

Can this information be scraped using beautiful soup or do I need to use another tool like scrapy? (I prefer not to use selenium if possible).

Comment: you should use example.com instead of your real website, just my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

The data you see is loaded from external URL via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. To load the data you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/Search/products"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0",
}

payload = {
    "Filters": [],
    "IsSpecial": False,
    "Location": "/shop/search/products?searchTerm=uncle%20tobys%20oats%20500g&sortBy=TraderRelevance",
    "PageNumber": 1,
    "PageSize": 36,
    "SearchTerm": "uncle tobys oats 500g",
    "SortType": "TraderRelevance",
}


with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies
    s.get(
        "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/search/products?searchTerm=uncle%20tobys%20oats%20500g&sortBy=TraderRelevance",
        headers=headers,
    )

    # load actual data
    data = s.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers).json()

    # uncomment to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for p in data["Products"]:
        print("{:<60} {}$".format(p["DisplayName"], p["Products"][0]["Price"]))
```

Prints:

```
Uncle Tobys Oats Traditional Rolled Oats Porridge 500g       4.5$
Uncle Tobys Oats Quick Oats Porridge Porridge 500g           4.5$
```

Comment: I didn't get any output with the above code

Comment: @Jacob Make sure you haven't got Captcha response from the server...

Comment: I don't get a captcha response for the website. The code runs continuously with no output. I am also getting an error when accessing the api URL. Could you clarify your process for this particular script?

Comment: @Jacob Running the script I have in my answer produces the required output.